# > Task :dr.pogodin_react-native-static-server:buildCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a][lighttpd] FAILED

Tags: android, react-native

Please I'm trying to use this https://www.npmjs.com/package/@dr.pogodin/react-native-static-server
on my react native expo application and when I run the project with the command: npx expo run:android on Ubuntu. I get this error. Could you please help?

> Task :dr.pogodin_react-native-static-server:buildCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a][lighttpd] FAILED
> C/C++: ninja: error: 'sysroot/bin/pcre2-config: 3: -: not found-L/lib -lpcre2-8', needed by '../../../../build/intermediates/cxx/Debug/74ev68g3/obj/arm64-v8a/liblighttpd.so', missing and no known rule to make it

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':dr.pogodin_react-native-static-server:buildCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a][lighttpd]'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: ninja: Entering directory `/home/peace/Ramses - Work/maps-app/node_modules/@dr.pogodin/react-native-static-server/android/.cxx/Debug/74ev68g3/arm64-v8a'

Thanks in advance

I couldn't find much about solutions on the internet google/chatgpt

I tried to install libpcre2 by using:
sudo apt-get install libpcre2-dev

But still It didn't work out

Comment: Do not spam different internet forums with same question and then fail to at least link them.  Duplicated here: https://github.com/birdofpreyru/react-native-static-server/issues/102 (and possibly elsewhere)